Same minimizer over all induced norms in Hilbert Projection Theorem?
The Hilbert Projection Theorem states the following:

Let $\left(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle \right)$ be a Hilbert space with induced norm $ \lVert \cdot \rVert $ and let any nonempty closed convex $ C \subseteq V $. Then, for any $x \in V$, there exists a unique $z \in C$ such that $\lVert x - z \rVert = \inf_{y \in C} \lVert x - y \rVert $.

My question:

Assuming that $V, C$ and $x$ are fixed, does the aforementioned minimizer $z$ depend on the choice of the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ or is it the same over all possible complex inner products?


It depends on the norm (and thus on the inner product)

Thank you. Is there any easy counterexample to show that?

Consider $V_1=V_2=\mathbb{C}^2,$ $C=\mathbb{C}(1,1).$ Let $$\langle x,y\rangle_1=x_1\overline{y_1}+ x_2\overline{y_2},\\\langle x,y\rangle_2=x_1\overline{y_1}+ 8x_2\overline{y_2}$$ be the inner products in $V_1$ and $V_2,$ respectively. For $x=(1,-1)$ the element $z=(0,0)$ is the closest with respect to the first inner product as $x\perp C.$ We have  $\|x-z\|_2=3.$ For $z'=(-1,-1)$ we get $\|x-z'\|_2=2,$ hence $(0,0)$ is not the closest point with respect to the second inner product.
In general if $V=V_1=V_2$ is equipped with two inner products, which are not multiple of each other, then the are two elements $x,y$ such that
$$\langle x,y\rangle_1 =0,\quad \langle x,y\rangle_2\neq 0$$ Then for $C=\mathbb{C}y$ the element $0$ is the closest to $x$ with respect to the first inner product. However  it is not the closest to $x$ with respect to the second inner product as $x\not\perp C$ with respect to this inner product. The closest element is equal $ay$ such that $$\langle x-ay,y\rangle_2=0$$ i.e. $a={\langle x,y\rangle_2\over \langle y,y\rangle_2}.$

Thank you very much!
